# person who just seems to be doing tag edits all day

Tags: discussion, edits, serial-editing

Doing reviews I came across a series of tag edits in which the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag was removed from a question. That was the only change to the question. Since I saw this a few days ago from the same user, I took a look at their profile just now.

Looking at their reputation changes it appears they are going through questions doing tag changes, continuously getting a +2 reputation bump each time.

This just seems a bit excessive so I thought to bring this behavior up as question.

I suppose the only harm that I see is an excessive review queue.

Comment: Usually, more than just the tag can be improved about a question. Tag-only edits are often too minor. If that user is systematically suggesting edits containing _only_ a tag edit, you could flag one of the posts, explaining the situation (Link to some suggestions).

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate link.  I took a look and read over the answers there. I will just Reject if tag only edits come up that don't seem reasonable when reviewing.

Comment: Since he's [back at it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12635604), I took the liberty of leaving a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094962/c-strangely-formatted-hexadecimal-output#comment62929502_19094962) and linking to this question.

Comment: @BenjaminW. yep, that is the person. I actually wondered if it was a bot of some kind since the time between edits seems kind of quick for a human being.

Comment: He's certainly prolific at > 100 accepted edits per day...

Comment: @BenjaminW. well rejecting the edits makes my 20 review limit go fast! And I did a rollback on one of them just to get the Cleanup badge!

Comment: It's somewhat ironic that this was bumped to the front page of meta [via a tag-only edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/325790/revisions).

Comment: @zcoop98 Yep, a bit ironic. I looked back at this question then looked at the question it is a dupe of and decided to match up the tags.